# Custom screen lock for disable back button,home button,settings button using Android

Tags: java, android

Hi My requirement is like this. I have an activity in that I want to disable back button, menu button, home button screen settings button. When I touch on that screen I open one alert dialog with two buttons. If I click ok button all the buttons are enabled and my app is exit.

Thats my requirement. If anyone knows about this, please reply me as soon as possible. Quick reply is Very very appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you must specify your activity as `android.category.HOME`.
And when you finish your activity (press ok button) you must start default launcher on phone.
But it's mean that on every home button press you will see your activity. To prevent this you must determine how your activity was started.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather override onKeyDown method

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            //DO NOTHING
        }if(keyCode == ..etc){
                        //Still do nothing
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

This way you will have full control of what happens. 
Regards,
Robert

Comment: No, with this way you can't disable home button. For security reason home button always return to launcher app.

Comment: Just like Sure lock, toddlerlock i need to block entire home screen including settings buton, and it wont open any thing. after that i launch one alert dialog,Once i click on alertdialog ok button then only home screen is enabled

Comment: But The above code is not working in android ICS 4.0 and 3.2 also not working.